# Custom Page Number in TCPDF

Tags: tcpdf

i'm using TCPDF to generate my pdf. I have no idea for reset starting page number. I mean, i will generate report that starting page numer 3 (not 1) in footer, but the second page increment by 2 (3,5,6,7 etc)

Here is my code :

```
$_SESSION["hal"] = $_POST["hal"];
$_SESSION["f"] = $_POST["f"];


class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {

        // Position at 25 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-25);
        // Set font

        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'b', 8);

        // Page number

        $this->Cell(0, 15,$_SESSION["f"]." ". $_SESSION["hal"], 'T', false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
                $_SESSION["hal"]++;
    }
}
```

Can someone help please..

Answer (score 0):

Done..

$_SESSION["hal"] = $_POST["hal"];
$_SESSION["f"] = $_POST["f"];

class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

```
// Page footer
public function Footer() {

    // Position at 25 mm from bottom
    $this->SetY(-25);
    // Set font

    $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'b', 8);

    // Page number
    //i add var to store current page
    $halaman = $this->PageNo();
    $this->Cell(0, 15,$_SESSION["f"]." ". ($halaman+$_SESSION["hal"]), 'T', false, 'R', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

a other way is to use Page Groups. Better with no need of SESSION.

To start the Group:

```
$this->startPageGroup();
```

and to print:

```
$w_page = isset($this->l['w_page']) ? $this->l['w_page'].' ' : '';
if (empty($this->pagegroups)) {
   $pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getAliasNumPage().' / '.$this->getAliasNbPages();
} else {
$pagenumtxt = $w_page.$this->getPageNumGroupAlias().' / '.$this->getPageGroupAlias();
$this->Cell(0, 0, $pagenumtxt, 'T', 0, 'L');
```